# Differentiability of maps with quotient space as target set

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, partial-derivative, quotient-spaces

Let $U\subset R^d$ open, $T>0$ and $\phi: U \to \mathbb{R}/{T\mathbb{Z}}$.

What is the definition of $\phi$ being $C^k$ ? And how i get the partial derivatives in general?

Can you recommend me literature about it?

Thanks, 
Thomas

Comment: For continuity, you need to specify the topology on $\mathbb R/T\mathbb Z$. You are probably thinking about quotient topology here. To get a meaningful notion of differentiability, you will at least need a distance on your target space or deal with notions from algebraic geometry. Anyway, for me it is not clear, what $\mathbb R/T\mathbb Z$ looks like. Can you specify the equivalence relation?

Comment: yes, $x\equiv y:\iff \exists n\in\mathbb{Z}: x-y=nT $. I think i need to deal with notions from algebraic geometry.

Comment: What is the context of your question? $\mathbb{R}/{T\mathbb{Z}}$ has the structure of a smooth manifold which would answer your question

Comment: @James:   To talk about smoothness, one could also use differential geometry via manfiolds (with no metric).

Comment: @JasonDeVito You are right. But the one from differential geometry uses that locally you are given a map between $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ so there implicitly is a metric involved. Though you are right that my comment on this wasn't rally accurate.

Comment: @James:  I didn't think about the implicit use of the metric - good point!

Comment: Context: I consider something like a "lift"  $ \tilde{\phi}: U\to \mathbb{R} $ s.t. $ \tilde{\phi}(x) mod T= \phi(x), x\in U $ with $t\ mod T:= t + T\mathbb{Z}, t\in\mathbb{R} $. The claim is that $ \partial_i  \tilde{\phi}= \partial_i  \phi$. But i cant see why. So my idea was to understand in more detail the definition of the partial derivative for $\phi$.

Comment: Since $\pi\circ\bar \phi = \phi$, where $\pi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R/T\mathbb Z$ denotes the quotient map, $\partial_i\phi =\partial_i (\pi \circ\bar \phi)=(\partial_i \pi\circ \bar\phi)\cdot \partial_i \bar\phi$. I think there are a few things to check here, e.g. the differentiability of $\pi$. Your claim seems to be that  $\partial_i \pi\circ \bar\phi=1$ but I don't see no immediate reason for this to hold. Why do you think its true?